# WebJobs storage with Managed Identity

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

By default WebJobs requires to specify Azure Storage account using AzureWebJobsStorage connection string.

But I already have access to my storage with Managed Identity:

```
AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
string accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://storage.azure.com/");
StorageCredentials storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(new TokenCredential(accessToken));
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, "mystorageaccount", "core.windows.net", true);
```

Can I configure WebJobs to use this cloudStorageAccount instead of AzureWebJobsStorage connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I configure WebJobs to use this cloudStorageAccount instead of AzureWebJobsStorage connection string?

Yes, you could use `cloudStorageAccount` to get blob account and do some operation on blobs. However, you still need to provide `AzureWebJobsDashboard` and `AzureWebJobsStorage` when you  use Webjob. Because they are not only connectionstring, they are also the log path.

In my test, I set `AzureWebJobsStorage` value with `storage1` connection and in code I get `storage2` account and it works.

```
AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
string accessToken = azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://storage.azure.com/").Result;
StorageCredentials storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(new TokenCredential(accessToken));
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, "storage2", "core.windows.net", true);
CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("hello.txt");
cloudBlockBlob.UploadTextAsync("aaaaaaaa").Wait();
```

For more details about assign role and get access token you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-msi).

Comment: So if I understand correctly I get nothing by assigning Managed identity to Azure function to access storage account using `IBinder`. I won't get rid of connection string anyway?